# Making a textbox.text a required field

Tags: c#, textbox

Using VS2019. C#. I've toyed with ways to make fields on my forms required. i.e. A customer name, which is a textbox obviously. You can't save anything unless you provide this information...

What is the easiest way?
I've done the

```
IF (txtCustName.Text != null)
{
do this...
}
else
{
this
}
```

Even tried setting the tag property to a value of 1 (one) and check all controls on the form for this value.
I have no formal code training-wise. Thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: There is no built in class or method to do that. I will suggest you to write an Extension method for the TextBox class named IsValid and write all the validation rules inside of it. 

Or else you can use Fluent Validation Nuget package also.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
if (textBox1.Text == null || textBox1.Text == "")
{
  MessageBox.Show("please fill this textbox");
  return;
}
else
{
  //the saving code
}
```

to stop the current code from completing the code use return

if the textbox is empty, it will stop

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31719514)

Comment: Note:  there is a [String.IsNullOrEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-6.0) function.